"I will move" vs "I will be moving"?
Consider the two phrases,

I will move to Seattle in the summer.


I will be moving to Seattle in the summer.

Are the two phrase identical? Is there any situation one is preferable over another?

You don't actually need the explicit future here. "I move to Seattle in the summer" is syntactically fine - just a bit dated / formal. And "I am / I'm moving to Seattle in the summer" is not only perfectly natural, it could even be more common than your second example. It's really just a matter of emphasis. If your current state is significantly influenced or preoccupied with the future move, it's better not to include will, which puts more "distance" between the speaker and his intended future action.

You mean "Do they have identical meanings?" (obviously they are not identical).
Yes, they mean the same, but there is a slight difference in register. The first is a plain statement of future intention, such as you might use in an official context. The second is more informal, such as you might use in everyday conversation.

They are not identical? I mean, I thought they were interchangeable.

Identical means exactly the same. Two sentences containing some different words are not identical.

Thanks for the clarification.
